# How to apply in serilog config setting, to generate new log per session from appsetting.json (not from code)

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I am Trying to configure Serilog via json config(Not via code) for WFP app, I have multiple Exe within my solution, Objective is to have single appsetting.json config for all my Exe's that are part of the solution. So, I tried "shared" option(from appsetting.json) for sharing log file with multiple process which dint work. So now looking for a way to generate new log for each session(again from appsetting.json not from code). So,far this is how my config looks

```
{
    "Name": "RollingFile",
    "Args": {
      "pathFormat": "%userprofile%\\Logs\\Rolling-{Date}.json",
      "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
      "fileSizeLimitBytes": 512000,
      "retainedFileCountLimit": 100,
      "shared": true
    }
  }
```

Comment: _Serilog.Sinks.Map_ is usually the solution for this, but it's not JSON-configurable. The `shared` flag is normally the right way to go, as long as the app's run by only one user. Could be quicker to work on debugging that option?

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt is it possible to update only the file name while building configuration, like ReadfromConfiguration(), and after that update only the file name in code?

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt Went through Map, Let me see if map can help me updating the file name alone from code, and reg. the app, it is possible for multiple users to run that app, but diff users will have seperate log in their userprofile. Shared situation, is parent app is using the log file to log info and a child app triggered from Parent does some activity and finishes the work and gets closed. The Child app's content never gets into the log file. If I run child app seperately then the content is logged in the log file correctly.